# PHP round minutes when hour ends

Tags: php

I'm looking for a posibility to set minutes to "00" instead of "60". I have following code:

```
$minute = date('i');
$minutesround = round($minute / 10) * 10;
$hour = date('H');
$minutesround = str_pad($minutesround, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); 
$time = $hour . $minutesround;
echo $time;
```

My problem: If it is eg. 4:56pm the output should like this: **1700** 
but in my case, I get this **1660**

Someone has an idea, how to realize this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well:

```
$myRoundedTime = round(time()/600) * 600; // round time to nearest 6th of an hour
$time = date('Hi', $myRoundedTime);
echo $time;
```

A working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2b595683d9adf8e5273cbdef775bf69b6c036d4

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` statement should do the trick

```
$hour = date('H');
if($minutesround == 60) {
    $minutesround = 0;
    $hour++;
    if($hour == 24) $hour = '00';
}
```

Comment: Its not working.....i write same code <?php
$minute = date('i');
$minutesround = round($minute / 10) * 10;
$hour = date('H');
$minutesround = str_pad($minutesround, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); 
$hour = date('H');
if($minutesround == 60) {
    $minutesround = 0;
    $hour++;
}
$time = $hour . $minutesround;
echo $time;

?>
 gives me o/p 1240.....

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap so? 1240 should be the correct output for times 12:35 - 13:45